# ScrollView scrolls out of constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints, uistackview

I have a `UIScrollView` and a `UIStackView` inside of it. My problem is that when scrolling, the content is scrolling out of its constraints. Why is that happening? Do I have to set some other `constraints`?

[image][image]

These are my `constraints`:

```
view.addSubview(theScrollView)
theScrollView.addSubview(theStackView)

    theScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    theScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    theScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    theScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    theStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

`theLabel` is the "Konto erstellen" at the top. Any idea how I can fit it ?

If there is anything unclear just let me know.

Comment: have tried debugging the view using the view hierarchy debugger?

Comment: yes, the `stackView` and `scrollView` are in place but somehow the items inside the `stackView` are outside of it

Comment: Check that `theScrollView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: it is. both for `scrollVIew` and `stackView``

Comment: here is my full project: https://github.com/DieGlueckswurst/Wishlist   maybe that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SignUpViewController` class...

- you add `theScrollView` to `view`
- you add `theStackView` to `theScrollView`
- you add views to `theStackView`

  - theStackView.addArrangedSubview(emailView)
  - theStackView.addArrangedSubview(anzeigeNameView)
  - theStackView.addArrangedSubview(usernameView)
  - usw.

***But*** you then add other views to `view`:

- view.addSubview(emailTextField)
- view.addSubview(anzeigeNameTextField)
- view.addSubview(usernameTextField)

You then constrain those views to the views that are in `theStackView`. When you scroll the content, those view move with the stack view's subviews, but they are ***outside*** the hierarchy of the scroll view.

Instead, you need to do this:

```
    view.addSubview(theScrollView)
    theScrollView.addSubview(theStackView)

    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(emailView)
    emailView.addSubview(emailTextField)
    //view.addSubview(emailTextField)

    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(anzeigeNameView)
    anzeigeNameView.addSubview(anzeigeNameTextField)
    //view.addSubview(anzeigeNameTextField)

    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(usernameView)
    usernameView.addSubview(usernameTextField)
    //view.addSubview(usernameTextField)
```

Now your text fields will be subviews of their respective views, which are arranged subviews of the stack view.

You may need to adjust your constraints after doing this.

Comment: mmmm, that actually fixed it thanks! I know I had it like this before but I changed because somethings wasn't working like it should. However everything works just fine right now. Thanks  for your help :)